# Get the greatest time contant of a system's output given its expression

Tags: control-systems

Let $y(t)$ be a function that consists of a sum of terms, each of which is in general a product of an exponential function $e^{\sigma t}$, and a sine function $\sin{\omega t}$ or cosine function $\cos{\omega t}$ with some amplitude (it could also have a potential function $t^n$, but for the sake of simplicity let's assume $y$ has no terms with such factor). So $y$ has the general form

$y(t) = 2 e^{\sigma_1 t} (a_1 \cos{\omega_1 t} + b_1 \sin{\omega_1 t}) u(t) + 2 e^{\sigma_2 t} (a_2 \cos{\omega_2 t} + b_2 \sin{\omega_2 t}) u(t) + \cdots$

In other words, $y$ is the output of a continuous LTI system with no repeated poles.

My question is, **how do we get the greatest time constant of the output**, assuming the system is stable with a bounded input?

My proposed solution: Since we know the expression of $y(t)$, one way I think of tackling this problem is by following these steps:

1. Get each term of $y$. This results in a list $\{ 2 e^{\sigma_1 t} (a_1 \cos{\omega_1 t} + b_1 \sin{\omega_1 t}) u(t), 2 e^{\sigma_2 t} (a_2 \cos{\omega_2 t} + b_2 \sin{\omega_2 t}) u(t), \dots \}$
2. For each term, identify/get the exponential factor. This results in a list $\{ e^{\sigma_1 t}, e^{\sigma_2 t}, \dots \}$.
3. For each exponential factor, get the coefficient of the exponent (i.e. the Neper frequency). This results in a list $\{ \sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots \}$.
4. For each Neper frequency, get the negative of the inverse of it. This results in a list of $\{ \tau_1, \tau_2, \dots \}$, where $\tau_i = -1/ \sigma_i$.
5. Get the greatest time constant. This results in $\tau_{\text{max}}$.

While this algorithm is pretty descent for the kind of systems I'm studying, my problem is I don't know how to implement/code this. Do you know how? Or **do you know another way?** For the last step though, we could use the `Max[]` function of Mathematica.

**EDIT**: As an example, consider the output

$y(t) = [1 - 0.14 e^{-2.59 t} + 0.16 e^{-0.31 t} - 2 e^{-0.05 t} (0.51 \cos{0.95 t} + 0.20 \sin{0.95 t})] u(t)$

All of the coefficients of the  exponents of exponential factors are non-positive, so the output is bounded and we can use the algorithm. After applying steps 1 to 3, Mathematica should get the list `{-2.59, -0.31, -0.05}`. For step 4, it gets the inverse of each element of the list and multiplies it by -1, getting the list `{0.39, 3.23, 20}`. For step 5, the `Max[]` function applied to the previous list should return `20`, which is the greatest time constant of the output.

By the way, I just realized we can make the algorithm a bit more efficient. Change step 4 as: "Get the `Min[]` of the list obtained in step 3." And change step 5: "Get the inverse of the minimum element obtained and multiply it by -1."

Comment: it will be easier to answe if you show a MWE of an actual expression to use to test with with any concrete values they might have.

Comment: @Nasser I've added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[y, t, x, u];
y[t_] := (1 - 0.14*Exp[-2.59*t] + 0.16*Exp[-0.31*t] - 
        2*Exp[-0.05*t]*(0.51*Cos[0.95*t] + 0.2*Sin[0.95*t]))*u[t]; 

getPatterns[expr_, pat_] := Last[Reap[expr /. a:pat :> Sow[a], _, Sequence @@ #2 & ]]; 

(*r = getPatterns[y[t], Exp[x__]];*)
r = getPatterns[y[t], Exp[_. t + _.]]; (*may be better*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
If[Length[r] > 0, Max[Cases[r, Exp[(x_.)*t] :> -x^(-1)]]]
(*20*)
```

The function `getPatterns` above is thanks to Carl Woll